# iOS: How to install a profile to monitor user activity

Tags: ios, text, sms, profile

Is there a way to monito user activity (eg, texts, browsing, calls) perhaps by asking the user to install a profile?  This is not not hack someone’s phone; it is for parents to monitor their kid’s activity.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot because of sandboxing.

Comment: There are iOS app that do this. It does require the user to install a profile. An example app is AirWatch.

Comment: Even an MDM like AirWatch can't read a users texts or monitor other activity.

Comment: @Paulw11 AirWatch can and does that. Also, there are several parental control apps is the AppStore that do the same

Comment: No, it [can't](https://blogs.air-watch.com/2016/02/3-things-need-know-airwatch-privacy-end-users/#.WjbV3abZWf0). It can monitor usage of apps that are installed and managed by the MDM. This is typically how the parental control product work; they disable the managed apps, such as Facebook, at certain times of the day.